# sending xml in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.emailmessage.culture

Tags: c#, xml, email, outlook

I am trying to send an XML string through exchange service here is my code

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };


            exService.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            exService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("set of credentials");
            exService.Url = new Uri("https://url");

 public void SendMail(string subject, string body, string to)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
            EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(exService);
#if DEBUG
            msg.ToRecipients.Add("test@address.com");
#else
            msg.ToRecipients.Add(to);
#endif
            msg.Body = body;
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Send();
}}
```

The subject and to are as you would guess string objects of those pieces of information. The body is a string comprised of XML. I have use this code before with HTML and the emails came out fine. i need to use it with XML for a desktop or service application. Currently when I put in an XML string the emails come out blank but if I put in a string literal it comes out fine. Outlook is reporting the emails as HTML rather than plain text when they arrive in outlook. What do I need to add to make the XML appear normally in the emails received?

Answer (score 0):

I sound a solution,  I just has to surround the body with  tags rather than  so that exchange would accept the string as html